# Code format linter for Java

Tags: java

I work in a project where it is accessed by many developers, some follow code formatting standards, while some don't. Is there any code format linter available for a java project ?

Comment: I really should vote to close this since it's requesting a resource which isn't supposed to be allowed on StackOverflow.  But ... http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

In IntelliJ: <kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>

In Netbeans: <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>